# Does OpenLDAP olcAccess support quorum of users

Tags: openldap

For example, we have role with sensitive access or privileges. And have two users with less sensitive privileges' role.
We want to grant to this users permission to set more sensitive role to user, but only in a quorum of exact two users.
Can we do this?

I think, we can use olcAccess "sets", but these is poorly documented...

Answer (score 0):

You can define sets of users and groups using the `"sets"` technique, and then use those sets in access control rules. The two users who are permitted to grant sensitive access may be combined into a set, and any modifications to sensitive access could then need to be approved by at least two users in that set.

*EXAMPLE:*

```
# Define a set of users who can grant sensitive access
olcAccessSet: sensitive-admins {user1, user2}

# Require at least two members of the sensitive-admins set to grant sensitive access
olcAccess: {2}to * by group=sensitive-admins approve:sensitive_access
olcAccess: {0}to * by group=sensitive-admins read
```

In this example, the first olcAccess rule grants the `"approve:sensitive_access"` permission to members of the `"sensitive-admins"` group, but requires that at least two members of the group approve the request. The second olcAccess rule grants read access to the same group.

You should test any access control changes in a non-production environment before deploying them to your production LDAP server.

Comment: Sorry, what is `"approve:sensitive_access"` clause? As far as I know, there is no such keyword in olcAccess attribute...